¿Cómo puedo hacer válida una respuesta cuando la secuencia es zero-length? Python
Hay una función en donde se evalúa la validez de una cadena de ADN. Si la cadena tiene 'ATCG' es válida, pero si la cadena tiene otras letras combinadas con 'ATCG' es inválida. El problema es que cuando el argumento en la cadena está vacío debe ser válido también. Pero no sé cómo lograrlo.
Esto es lo que tengo:
for char in dna:
        if char not in'ATCG':
            return False
    for char in dna:
        if char in 'ATCG':
            return all(dna)


Cuando lo testeo en la shell, y uso la función is_valid_sequence('') no obtengo ninguna respuesta, simplemente sigue la línea.

Una forma muy simple es usar all() junto a un simple generador que itere sobre la secuencia y use el operador de pertenencia in:
def is_valid_sequence(secuence):
    return all(base in "ATGC" for base in secuence)


>>> is_valid_sequence("AGTGGC")
True
>>> is_valid_sequence("AGTGGCUGT")
False
>>> is_valid_sequence("")
True


all() lleva a cabo una evaluación mínima (short-circuit), es decir retorna en cuanto encuentre un False, dejando de evaluar el resto.
Tal como tienes tu función, si se le ingresa una cadena vacía retornará None (valor de retorno por defecto de todo método/función en Python). Esto se debe a que, si la cadena está vacía, el for que la recorre no iterará siquiera una vez, dado que tus returns están dentro de estos for ninguno se ejecutará.
No se muy bien cual era tu idea con el segundo for, pero all(dna) retorna True para cualquier cadena, vacía o no. de cualquier forma este segundo ciclo es innecesario, bastaría con:
def is_valid_sequence(dna):
    for char in dna:
        if char not in'ATCG':
            return False
    return True

Esta función retornará True siempre y cuando el return dentro del for no se ejecute, lo que incluye las cadenas vacías.

Gracias, utilicé el segundo for porque Phyton seguía poniendo True aunque la respuesta fuera False, por eso lo hice. Pero ya con tu respuesta, ese problema se solucionó.

Con solo agregar un if dna=="" y darle return válido antes del for debería ser suficiente

¿Es mucho trabajo publicar el código completo?

Por curiosidad he consultado en ChatGTP y contesta lo siguiente.
El problema principal es que estás retornando False en el primer bucle for cuando encuentras un carácter que no está en 'ATCG'. Esto significa que si la cadena está vacía, el bucle no se ejecutará y la función retornará False antes de verificar si la cadena está vacía.
Aquí tienes una forma de corregirlo:
def is_valid_sequence(dna):
    # Verificar si la cadena está vacía
    if not dna:
        return True
    
    # Verificar si todos los caracteres son 'ATCG'
    for char in dna:
        if char not in 'ATCG':
            return False
    
    # Si no se encontraron caracteres que no son 'ATCG', la cadena es válida
    return True

# Ejemplo de uso:
print(is_valid_sequence('ATCG'))  # True
print(is_valid_sequence('ATCGB'))  # False
print(is_valid_sequence(''))  # True

En esta versión de la función, primero se verifica si la cadena está vacía. Si lo está, la función retorna True. Luego, si la cadena no está vacía, se recorre cada carácter. Si se encuentra un carácter que no está en 'ATCG', la función retorna False. Si el bucle termina sin encontrar ningún carácter inválido, la función retorna True.

Recuerda que el uso de AI en el sitio está prohibido, tu cuenta puede ser suspendida por plagio., revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

ChatGPT se equivoca...para variar... la función retorna None si se le ingresa una cadena vacía no False... Además, el primer condicional sobra, si el ciclo no itera o se completa sin ejecutar el condicional se ejecutará el return final, eso incluye las cadenas de entrada vacías...

Más allá de la prohibición y la equivocación, no consideres lo que dice una ia, sobre todo si su modelo fue entrenado con paginas web, como verdad absoluta. Revisá si la respuesta es correcta. Considera que he leido de chatgpt cosas donde se afirma que "Venus es el planeta más cercano al sol". Además, si el usuario quisiera una respuesta cruda de chatgpt, puede ir a la pagina del mismo, no a SOEs.

Pido disculpas y tomo buena nota.
